# Javascript: Bind methods from another class to 'this' keyword in a functional method

Tags: javascript, bind, mixins, arrow-functions

I have written some base classes for a Rest API. I have some need now to use a functional wrapper for the handler rather than a class which extends this base Rest API class.

However, I do not want to duplicate all the work I've done to allow this wrapper method to work.

I have tried the following to get this to work

```js
// api.ts

const handler = (e: APIGatewayEvent, ctx: Context) =>
  functionalRestLambdaHandler(e, ctx, (e: APIGatewayEvent, ctx: Context) => {
    const handler = new ApiHandler(e, ctx);
    const { id } = this.getPathParameters();
    const { assigned = false } = this.getQueryStringParameters();
    try {
      return this.success(handler.handle(id, assigned));
    } catch (e) {
      return this.error(e);
    }
  });
```

```js
//baseHandler.ts

export abstract class RestLambdaHandler extends BaseLambdaHandler<APIGatewayProxyEvent> {
  ...

  async success<T>(
    body?: T,
    headers?: Headers,
  ): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {
    ...
  }

  getHeaders<T extends StringMap>(): T {
    ...
  }

  getPathParameters<T extends StringMap>(): T {
    ...
  }

  getQueryStringParameters<T extends StringMap>(): T {
    ...
  }

  getBody<T>(): T {
    ...
  }

}

export const functionalRestLambdaHandler = (
  e: APIGatewayProxyEvent,
  ctx: Context,
  handler: (
    event: APIGatewayProxyEvent,
    context: Context,
  ) => Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult>
) => {
  function arrowBind<T>(
    e: APIGatewayProxyEvent,
    ctx: Context,
    context: T,
    fn: (
      event: APIGatewayProxyEvent,
      context: Context,
    ) => Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult>
  ): typeof fn & T {
    let arrowFn;
    return function(e: APIGatewayProxyEvent, ctx: Context) {
      arrowFn = eval(fn.toString());
      return arrowFn(e, ctx);
    }.call({ e, ctx, context });
  }
  return arrowBind(e, ctx, { ...RestLambdaHandler }, handler);
};
```

When I `console.log` out `this` in the API handler I see the class member properties (things such as the `headers` property etc); however, I do not see any of the methods (things such as the method `this.getHeaders()`, `this.success()` etc.).

How can I bind all the methods from the RestLambdaHandler class to the `this` keyword in the handler method?

Edit:
I ended up simply doing the following

```js
export const createRestLambdaHandler = (
  event: APIGatewayProxyEvent,
  context: Context,
  handler: (...args: any[]) => Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult>
) => {
  class Handler extends RestLambdaHandler {}
  const restLambdaHandler = new Handler(event, context);
  return handler.call(restLambdaHandler);
};
```

This accomplishes what I needed to accomplish, with the one downside being you cannot use an arrow-function as the callback for the `functionalRestLambdaHandler`.

Comment: We can use parse `this` as variable

Comment: `arrowFn = eval(fn.toString());` ... I would never try to hack some variables into scope ... That just won't work.

Comment: Also you never pass any `e` or `ctx` to the most inner function, and `arrowBind` is totally superflouos.

Comment: Also what is `{ ...RestLambdaHandler }` supposed to do?

Comment: the `arrowBind` method is an attempt to bind methods/attributes to the `this` keyword in an arrow function, as `this` refers to `globalThis` in the arrow function without this. It is not totally superfluous, as without it, `this` does not contain any of the context provided (i.e. `e`, `ctx`, or the attributes in the `RestLambdaHandler`)


`{ ...RestLambdaHandler }` is an attempt to spread the member attributes and methods to the context, allowing them to be bound to `this` in the handler which is wrapped by the `functionalRestLambdaHandler`

Comment: (1) You set `this` of the inner anonymous function, not of `arrowBind`. (2) `RestLambdaHandler` is a class, not an instance.